# Matlab composite 'if' statement not giving expected result

Tags: matlab, for-loop

While writing a program for equation (5) from this paper http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1992PASJ...44..493K,

[image]

I think I have made some mistake (below). I don't know how to include the 'or' from the equation.

```
    if alpha_sgp<alpha<=(alpha_sgp-180)
        if p<=180-t
          P=p+t;
        else %p>180-t
          P=p+t-180;
        end
    elseif alpha<=alpha_sgp | (alpha_sgp-180)<alpha   
        if p>=t
          P=p-t;
        else %p<t
          P=p-t+180;
        end
    end
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: In this link to the paper:

http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?letter=.&classic=YES&bibcode=1992PASJ...44..493K&page=&type=SCREEN_VIEW&data_type=PDF_HIGH&send=GET&filetype=.pdf

Where is the algorithm that you're trying to implement?

Comment: Firstly, you should probably read [this reference on for loops](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html). Secondly, you should post what you want to do in pseudocode, if you want anyone to explain how it should be done in Matlab. In general, in Matlab, for loops are a "last resort" and nearly all operations should be done in vectorized form, not in loops, for performance reasons. But it's unclear whether this is possible in your problem.

Comment: Secondly: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Just a wild guess: In the paper you cite, I assume you are referring to equation (5). However, they implement their logic using `pi` - not `180`. Depending on the rest of your code, this can be an issue.

Comment: Yes @Schorsch,@Reinderien, I am referring to eq. (5). Also, pi here is in radian thats why I use 180 for that. I am trying to implement eq. (5) so that I can get the value of P. Here, alpha, p & t are Nx1 vectors & alpha_sgp is a single number.

Comment: Again, please be precise about your problem. What is not working?

Comment: Thanks @Schorsch for the prompt reply. Actually, I wanted to be sure that what I have implemented in Matlab looks correct before diving further with my problem. When I saw 'for' in eq (5) I tried playing with for-loop but found no room for that. So, I thought I am making some mistake. But it seems from your answer that my implementation looks correct.

Comment: Let me put it this way: Your syntax looks Matlab-ish. Just based on what you are showing here, I think a logic such as this should work. **BUT**: If it works in your case is impossible to know because the rest of your code/skills is unknown. Also, be aware of the [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a problem with your statement:

```
if alpha_sgp<alpha<=(alpha_sgp-180)
```

While this is syntactically correct in Matlab, it's not doing what you think it is.

Simple example:

```
a=1;b=2;c=3;
disp(a<b<c)
```

Will return `1` (true). BUT

```
disp(a<c<b)
```

Will ALSO return `1`. This has to do with order of operations, and the fact that a sub-expression of the type `a<b` will be evaluated (to `1`), before the result is compared to `c`. Thus

```
a<b<c
```

Is equivalent to

```
(a<b) < c
```

Is equivalent to

```
If ( (a < b) & (1 < c)) | ( (a >= b ) & (0 < c) )
```

What you actually want as your first line is

```
(alpha_sgp<alpha) & (alpha<=(alpha_sgp-180))
```

Quite apart from making sure that you do the conversions from degrees to radians right, etc. I recommend that you stick to radians - using the built in `pi` - rather than working in degrees, and having to use functions like `sind` instead of `sin`.

Also - you make a curious comment about "not knowing how to include `for`" - when there is no `for`, just an `or` in the equation. Could this be a typo on your part?

Finally - note that the second set of conditions are basically the inverse of the first - when `(alpha_sgp < alpha) & (alpha <= (alpha_sgp-180))` is false, then the converse is true. So in implementing your formula, you can replace the whole `elseif` line with just `else`.

Feel free to comment if you need further clarification.

Comment: +1 good explanation of logical operations.

Comment: @Schorsch - thanks for the first, and good catch on the second. There was a space missing, so the line of code (right after "What you actually want as your first line is") showed as text, and the first `<` symbol threw the HTML interpreter for a loop... Added one space, now I think it's ok.